# Why can't I set explain verbose options through nodejs driver?

Tags: mongodb

I am using `nodejs` driver to connect to MongoDB and tried the `Cursor.explain` method to explain query performance. The document about this API is from http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#explain. I wonder why it doesn't have the parameter for verbose options. In MongoDB shell, the explain method supports three different options: `'queryPlanner','executionStats','allPlansExecution'`. Why can't I set them through driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just found myself in need of the above (`.explain()` runs the `executionStats` variant by default, which can be crazy slow) the solution is:

```js
db.command({
  explain: {
    find: "collectionName",
    filter: {...},
    ...
  },
  verbosity: "queryPlanner"
});
```

see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/#dbcmd.explain for more details